# How to create a tab control where every tab item is connected with a different listbox

Tags: windows-phone-7

How can we create a tab control where every tab item is connected with a different listbox, so the view are different for every tab? I want to know what is the best solution for this, I tried two approaches:

1. All logic of tab activity is built in one class that is
   `mainPage.xaml.cs`
2. For every tab I create a new class and call it when a tab event
   fires

What is the best solution and if answer is second then what is procedure to add different view but the all the tab appear every time?

Or provide a link where I can get a full example of tab control usage in Windows Phone 7.

Answer (score 2):

Windows Phone does not provide a TabControl implementation, however, it does provide the unique `Pivot` control, which provides the same level of functionality and is documented on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.pivot%28v=VS.92%29.aspx). You might also find this post by Jeff Wilcox useful: http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/08/looking-ahead-at-panorama-and-pivot/

Comment: Even it does, the Pivot provides a much much better UI, which is more native to the phone, and to a touch UI in general. Swipes are **always** better than clicks, since they don't require movement of the hand.

Comment: It's not an official part of the framework, you need to add a reference to a regular Silverlight assembly, which although possible, is not recommended. I would always advocate using the controls that are native to the platform.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is an article](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/using-tabcontrol-windows-phone) I wrote on how to use the `TabControl` in a Windows Phone Silverlight application. It does not really abide the current UI guidelines, but it works. All you need to do is use `ListBox` controls as proper child elements.

Comment: Whilst I appreciate that it's _possible_ to use the TabControl, why would you advocate using it over a platform-specific and platform-optimised control that performs the same task (Pivot)?

Comment: I am not advocating it's usage - so far I haven't seen many apps with TabControl anyway. My point - it is possible and it can be invoked if necessary.

Comment: Sure, and I appreciate that, but I think as platform evangelists (even unofficial ones) we should be trying to help new developers produce better quality applications. So for this question, instead of pointing out that it can be done and how, why not tell them that they're thinking isn't aligned with good UX on the platform and how to do it properly?

Comment: Correct. That's why I mentioned that it does not abide the UI guidelines. Whether to use it or not - it is going to be the dev's choice.

Comment: Yes, I'm simply suggesting that your answer would be more complete if you also offered the "correct" solution and provided more guidance along the way :)

Comment: Thanx Dennis for your valuable suggestion, Actually i m beginner in window phone 7 ,i m not working with pivot so i just want link of  tutorial where i see how we use pivot  control....

Comment: actually i have five tab item in my application and   i just want show  all tab item when the  the app start but it not possible with pivot it quite possible with app bar control......

Comment: @shanu - Create a new "Pivot Application" from the "New Project" dialog to see how a pivot works. I know you can't see all of the tab boxes, but the user's will be more familiar with it (the mail app uses it).